# Failed to use mongrel on Windows server with Rails 3 and Ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongrel

I'm trying to install redmine on a windows 2008 server.
It works with webrick.
Now I'm trying to put it in production with mongrel.
But when I start mongrel I have the following error:

> E:/Ruby/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.1/http11 (LoadError)
>   from E:/Ruby/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>   from E:/Ruby/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:17:in `rescue in \<top (required)>'
>   from E:/Ruby/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:13:in`\'
>   from E:/Ruby/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>   from E:/Ruby/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>   from E:/Ruby/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:13:in `\<top (required)>'
>   from E:/Ruby/Ruby21/bin/mongrel_rails:23:in`load'
>   from E:/Ruby/Ruby21/bin/mongrel_rails:23:in `'

I don't really know Ruby and can't figure out what the error means.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with redmine, but I think problem is that you want to run Mongrel server, which is very old, and maybe not compatible with ruby2 (which you use). You can try add to Gemfile.local `gem 'thin'`, for example, and make `bundle install`. I hope this [manual](http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/32693) will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Unfortunately I have the same kind of issue with thin, failing to load eventmachine. But the two errors have something in common, the failing gems are postfixed with -x86-mingw32. CAn it be the source of the issues ?

Comment: After a lot of tries I have a better understanding of the way things work. Obviously gems postfixed with -x86-mingw32 contains libs in .so format and different versions of the .so files are provided for different versions of Ruby. mongrel only comes with libraries for ruby 1.8 and 1.9. Eventmachine is available for ruby 1.8, 1.9 and 2.0. But thanks to this blog [link](http://blog.cloud-mes.com/2014/10/06/compile-eventmachine-1-dot-0-3-in-ruby-2-dot-1-3-on-windows/) I was able to compile for ruby 2.1. Thanks for your help.